# how to interact with java from a binary converted javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html

For a solution of device/platform independent standalone application   with HTML 5+SVG+JavaScript , how to package JavaScript as binary for all devices  so that it is not exposed to users and also how to make calls to a java library from that hidden/packaged binary JavaScript? Tried with current available solutions like nodewebkit for making javascript as binary but making calls to java using java applet is not working from binary packaged JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

1. Are you asking about multiplatform development in JS?

In that case take a look at PhoneGap, Tide SDK, Enyo JS, MoSync there are plenty, and new one keep coming.

1. Are you asking about running JS in Java?

In that case there is Java Scripting API for that http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/

According to sample from http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/prog_guide/api.html

```
import javax.script.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ScriptVars {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ScriptEngineManager manager = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = manager.getEngineByName("nashorn");

        // create File object
        File f = new File("test.txt");

        // expose File object as a global variable to the engine
        engine.put("file", f);

        // evaluate JavaScript code and access the variable
        engine.eval("print(file.getAbsolutePath())");
    }
}
```

You can expose Java object as a Global Variable.
So I would go from there.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The requirement is -Javascript has to make calls to Java even after packaging the Javascript as binary. The final application will be HTML5+SVG+Javascript+java - having javascript as binary as user shoudn't be able to see the js code which ptherwise is visible with view source code.

Comment: JavaScript is loaded through html5 either in browser or packaged and launched by nodewebkit. Calls to java have to be made from javascript